# Проблема отправки запроса с CORS

Tags: reactjs, fetch, cors

При запросе из PostMan, запрос отправляется и приходит ответ
[image: Пример запроса postman]

```
  const submit = async () => {

    fetch('http://188.234.251.210:8000/API/REST/Authorization/LoginWith?username=Имя Фамиля', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      },

      data: 'пароль'
    }).then(res => console.log(res))
  }
```

С таким кодом у меня выходит ошибка

**Access to fetch at 'http://188.234.251.210:8000/API/REST/Authorization/LoginWith?username=%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

пробовал метод no-cors, но тогда мне ответ приходит без статуса, я не могу понять ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CORS с нами уже почти 20 лет, а вопросы всё те же…

Comment: Есть ощущене, что надо сделать после ответа что то вида `.then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res))`

Comment: @SwaD, если сделать как вы сказали то ошибка, "Unexpected end of input
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

Comment: @AlexeyTen,а вы знаете как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Знаю. https://doka.guide/tools/cors/ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors